# How to compare two datatables rows and make a new datatable?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datatable, dataset

I have two datatables. One datatable that has account and balance and the other datatable has the fee and the balance. For example: 
Datatable 1
111111    35.00
111112    50.00
Datatable 2
111111sf  5.00
111112sf  8.00

New datatable should show the account from datatable 1 and the total balance(datatable 1 and datatable 2)
111111   40.00
111112   58.00
how can I compare the two datatables to go through each row and add these values and then create a new datatable? I did it with three gridviews and List(Of string) but it was dirty. I would appreciate any help.
Here is my code:

```
    sqladapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECt account, balance FROM DEBT WHERE (account =   @account)", conn)
    sqladapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECt account, balance FROM DEBT WHERE (account = @account)", conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()


    sqladapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account", 111111)
    sqladapter2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account", 111111)

    sqladapter.Fill(ds, "WithSFDT")
    sqladapter2.Fill(ds, "WithoutSFDT")


    'get datatable
    Dim dtWith As DataTable = ds.Tables("WithSFDT")
    Dim dtWithout As DataTable = ds.Tables("WithoutSFDT")
```

Here is the dirty code in gridview:

```
     Dim itemlist As New List(Of String)


        For Each row1 As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            If row1.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                Dim gv1Value As String = row1.Cells(1).Text
                Dim gv1col3 As Decimal = row1.Cells(2).Text
                Dim lname As String = row1.Cells(3).Text
                Dim fname As String = row1.Cells(4).Text
                Dim TOdate As DateTime = row1.Cells(5).Text
                Dim debtnum As Integer = row1.Cells(6).Text



                For Each row2 As GridViewRow In GridView2.Rows
                    If row2.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                        Dim gv2Value As String = row2.Cells(3).Text
                        Dim gv2col3 As Decimal = row2.Cells(1).Text

                        If gv1Value.Contains(gv2Value) Then
                            GridView1.Visible = False
                            GridView2.Visible = False
                            GridView3.Visible = True


                            itemlist.Add(TOdate & " | " & gv1Value & " | " & fname & " " & lname & " " & " | " & gv1col3 + gv2col3 & " " & " | " & debtnum)

                        ElseIf gv2Value Is Nothing Then

                            GridView3.Visible = False
                            GridView1.Visible = True

                            'itemlist.Add(gv1col3 + gv2col3)
                            'list2.Add(gv1Value)

                        End If

                    End If
                Next

            End If


        Next
        If itemlist.Count > 0 Then


            GridView3.DataSource = itemlist
            GridView3.DataBind()
            GridView3.HeaderRow.Cells(0).Text = "T/O Date" & " | &nbsp; " & " Account" & " &nbsp; | " & " Name" & " &nbsp; | " & "Balance" & " | " & "Debt #"
            ' GridView3.HeaderRow.Cells(1).Text = " Balance"
            'GridView4.Columns.Add(
            GridView3.Visible = True


        End If
```

The problem with is is that the Gridview3 shows the itemlist in one row and it doesn't look like a table.

Comment: I think it will be cleaner if you can create sql query for the 3rd table, put the logic in query if possible. Btw, what is difference between Table WithSFDT and WithoutSFDT? Query statement, parameter value, and connection for filling both look all the same

Comment: I made a mistake and in both queries I entered from the same debt table. Its two different tables and actually my queries are extremely complicated that is why I broke it into two. The WithSFDT table include the accounts with service fee and the WithouSFDT include the account just with its balance. I'm going to include my    dirty code with 3 gridviews so you can have an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks for answering me.

Comment: *"The problem with is is that the Gridview3 shows the itemlist in one row"*.. I guess you meant in one column. Please clarify, is that the problem? you want GridView3 to show multiple columns instead

Comment: Initially I wanted to do this with datatables, but I'll settle with the Gridview. How can I show the list(of string) with multiple columns so when I pass it to Gridview it will have more than one column instead of one?